# How to use sanitize_callback?

Tags: theme-customizer, sanitization

Theme Check is telling me add_setting() should have a sanitize_callback function so I tried to add one.  This is for a color selector:

```
        $wp_customize->add_setting($setting_name, array(
            'default' => $default,
            'transport' => $transport,
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
        ));
```

The error doesn't go away.  Even if I make my own sanitize function, the error stays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was finding the error in some backup files I was keeping around.  Once I removed those files, the error went away.